# Keep track of connected sockets with socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

How do I keep track of all the connected clients in `socket.io`?

I have tried this on the server:

```
let numSockets = 0;

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  io.sockets.emit('numSockets', ++numSockets);

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    io.sockets.emit('numSockets', --numSockets);
  });
});
```

and this on the client:

```
const socket = io();

socket.on('numSockets', function (numSockets) {
  console.log(numSockets);
});
```

It does print a number, but the number, however, if I open 2 windows, it shows 4 connected sockets.

Is this the correct way to do it?

What I want to achieve is to print a list of the connected sockets' ids in a sidebar on my website, and let the user set a username (instead of the automatically generated id) if they want to.

But before moving on to this, I will make sure I can keep track of the sockets in a correct way.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that `io.sockets.emit(io.of('/').connected)` is a good idea because it will send a hash of socket objects which is a lot of data :-)

You can try the following function:

```
function findUsersConnected(room, namespace) {
  var names = [];
  var ns = io.of(namespace || "/");    

  if (ns) {
    for (var id in ns.connected) {
      if(room) {
        var roomKeys = Object.keys(ns.connected[id].rooms);
        for(var i in roomKeys) {
          if(roomKeys[i] == room) {
            if (ns.connected[id].username) {
              names.push(ns.connected[id].username);
            } else {
              names.push(ns.connected[id].id);
            }  
          }
        }
      } else {
        if (ns.connected[id].username) {
          names.push(ns.connected[id].username);
        } else {
          names.push(ns.connected[id].id);
        }  
      }
    }
  }
  return names.sort();
}
```

which returns an array of users connected to a room in a namespace. If a socket has not `socket.username` property then `socket.id` is used instead.

For instance:

```
var usersConnected = findUsersConnected();
var usersConnected = findUsersConnected('myRoom');
var usersConnected = findUsersConnected('myRoom', '/myNamespace');
```

Answer (score 0):

There's the [`Namespace#connected`](http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#namespace#connected:object) object that contains all sockets (keyed by their id) that are connected to a particular namespace.

To retrieve the socket id's of the default namespace (`/`):

```
let clientIds = Object.keys( io.of('/').connected );
```

(where `io` is the server instance)

Comment: So I should create a [middleware](http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#namespace#use(fn:function):namespace) and use `io.sockets.emit(io.of('/').connected)` inside it to tell all clients when a new socket has connected?

Comment: @mortensen yeah, that would send a list of socket id's to all connected clients.

Answer (score 0):

As of today, socket.io implemented a function called fetchSockets() on server side to retrieve all sockets that are currently connected on the server-side. (Source : https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-instance/#fetchSockets)

You can then use it like this :

```
const io = require("socket.io")

async function retrieveSockets() {
    const connectedSockets = await io.fetchSockets()
}
```

As far as i tested, you can even execute action on sockets thanks to that, like emitting events, joinings rooms...etc

Answer (score 0):

```
const count = io.engine.clientsCount;
```

This seems like a more inclusive approach and may be the same count of Socket instances in the main namespace as below. But depending on namespaces and usage they could be different.

```
const count2 = io.of("/").sockets.size;
```

https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-api/#engineclientscount

Answer (score -1):

I believe it is `Object.keys(io.sockets.connected).length`. Check server api http://socket.io/docs/server-api/